# Fetch global data for the whole app in Next.js on initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next.js application I have search filters.
Filters consist of checkboxes, and to render these checkboxes I need to fetch (GET) all possible options from the API.

Those filters are available on many pages, so regardless the page where user lands I need to fetch the data for filters immediately and put it in the local storage to avoid further excessive API calls. Putting API call in each page is not an option.

I see the one option is to put the API call in `getInitialProps` in `_app.js`, but then according to [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app) automatic static optimization will not work and every page in my app will be server-side rendered.

So what is the proper way to fetch such global data in Next.js?

Comment: For real data that you use on every page by default use a custom _app.js file. this is where you should get data for the whole app. But it sounds like you should make a request for filtered data and not filter it client side as this would not be scaleable

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### My use case

*Trying to fetch a jobs feed from Hygraph CMS to load globally and dynamically and for the entire app. I am using the jobs on every subpage but I don't render them into bespoke subpages and the data is often changing.*

There are two main things you need to be careful about:

- NextJS [hydration issues](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) (important when using localStorage if you don't check against if the client is "ready")
- Access to environmental variables. Every front-end app has this pre-built (no matter if it's NextJS or not) so this works for me because the *URL* in *lib/jobs.ts* is not a secret value.

#### The solution

Structure:

- _app.tsx
- pages/jobs.tsx
- lib/jobs.ts

##### _app.tsx

Use `useState` and pass your data to other components via props.

```
const JobsFeedFetcher = ({setFeed, children}) => {
   useEffect(() => {
      getJobsFeed()
         .then(jobs => {
            setFeed(jobs)
         })
   }, [])
   return <>{children}</>
}

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
   const [feed, setFeed] = useState<Job[]>([])
   return (
      <JobsFeedFetcher setFeed={setFeed}>
         <Component feed={feed} {...pageProps} />
      </JobsFeedFetcher>
   )
}
```

##### pages/jobs.tsx

```
export default function Jobs({feed}: AppProps) {
   return (
      <>
         <h2>Jobs</h2>
         {feed && feed.map(job => <p>{job.jobTitle}</p>)}
      </>
   )
}
```

##### lib/jobs.ts

```
export const getJobsFeed = async (): Promise<Job[]> => {
   const client = new GraphQLClient('URL')
   const query = gql`
      query Jobs {
        jobs {
          datePosted
          id
          jobRef
          location
          salary
          schoolType
          jobType
          jobTitle
        }
      }
  `
   const data = await client.request(query) as HygraphResponse
   return data.jobs
}
```

##### Note about using localStorage

It's not ideal in my opinion to use localStorage because you take away that from the data flow and NextJS spots inconsistency between SSR and client rendering result causing annoying and random errors.

You'd need to use something like:

```js
export const isClient = () => typeof window !== 'undefined'
```

If you truly want to do this, I've written a library called [rich-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rich-local-storage) to help with this. The browser localStorage **does not accept complex data types**, such as JS objects and arrays. This library allows you to easily define and maintain (reset) `expiry` and combines complex data into compressed primitive string value, then unpacking it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this filter is located on headermenu or sidebar menu?

If that is the case, I would suggest (an option other than _app.js) putting the API caller inside header/ sidebar component, and call the header/sidebar component on layout/ pages component.

Therefore, you will get the same behavior as what you've described (not invoking SSR on every pages and static optimization is still working because the concept is similar with the _app.js (just put it inside a structure).